# Search for dictionary key when the keys are tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
sample = {('red', 'blue', 'purple') : 'color', 'redo' : 'again', 'bred' : 'idk', 'greeting' : ('hi', 'hello')}

def search(c):
    if c in sample.keys():
        return sample[c]

print(search('red'))
```

This returns `None`. I know I can separate them and make multiple keys with the same value, but I'd really like to avoid doing so if I can. Can I?

And I would also like to be able to search for the values (which may be tuples as well) and get the corresponding keys.

Answer (score 5):

Using `iteritems()` would help you here. Update your `search()` method as follows. Should work fine.

```
def search(c):
    for k, v in sample.iteritems():
        if type(k) in [list, tuple, dict] and c in k:
            return v
        elif c == k:
            return v
```

---

In case of multiple occurrences of `c` inside the dictionary,

```
def search(c):
    found = [ ]
    for k, v in sample.iteritems():
        if type(k) in [list, tuple, dict] and c in k:
            found.append(v)
        elif c == k:
           found.append(v)
    return found
```

This will return a list of matching values inside dictionary.

---

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: That's good idea, but it wouldn't work in my case since I would have keys with multiple values (tuples) and multiple keys (tuples) for single values. Sorry still very new to this.

Comment: @BlackKnight I have updated the answer with minimal change. Let me know, would that suffice your needs. If not, could you add a broader perspective of the sample dict in the question?

Comment: sample = {('red', 'blue', 'purple') : 'color', 'redo' : 'again', 'bred' : 'idk'} Would be a better example to work with. Your answer would help if parts of some words didn't match parts of other words.

Comment: @BlackKnight Updated as you want it. Check it again, please.

Answer (score -1):

If you are not going to need to search by the whole tuple `('red', 'blue', 'purple')` then just construct your dictionary a little differently perhaps:

```
sample = {e: v for k, v in {('red', 'blue', 'purple') : 'color'}.items()
               for e in k}
```

Comment: I agree, but the question specifically stated "I can seperate them and make multiple keys with the same value, but I'd really like to avoid doing so if I can."

Comment: I'm creating a dictionary of an arbitrary language which I plan on translating to English (which includes synonyms and such). The OP was a simple example I was hoping would point out the issue I'm having, but I'm totally new to this and I guess I can't really express it the way I'd like to.